# While window Resize by using mouse my Datagrid displaying half in WPF

Tags: wpfdatagrid

In my WPF Project I have datagrid with scrollbar.
When i resize the window using mouse DataGrid displaying only halfpart.
and another issue is when open popup window and resized and closed the popup.
Again i opened,its opened previous height and width?

Can any guide me these two design issues?

Thanks,
Ramki